# How to use py.test fixtures without importing them

Tags: python, pytest

Say I have a file `fixtures.py` that defines a simple `py.test` fixture called `foobar`.

Normally I would have to import that fixture to use it (including all of the sub-fixtures), like this:

```
from fixtures import foobar

def test_bazinga(foobar):
```

Note that I also don't want to use a star import.

How do I import this fixture so that I can just write:

```
import fixtures

def test_bazinga(foobar):
```

Is this even possible? It seems like it, because `py.test` itself defines exactly such fixtures (e.g. `monkeypatch`).

Comment: Have you looked at how `py.test` does it?

Comment: put your fixtures in conftest.py

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Fixtures and their visibility are a bit odd in pytest. They don't require importing, but if you defined them in a `test_*.py` file, they'll only be available in that file.

You can however put them in a (project- or subfolder-wide) [conftest.py](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/plugins.html#requiring-loading-plugins-in-a-test-module-or-conftest-file) to use them in multiple files.

pytest-internal fixtures are simply defined in a [core plugin](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html), and thus available everywhere. In fact, a `conftest.py` is basically nothing else than a per-directory plugin.

You can also run `py.test --fixtures` to see where fixtures are coming from.

Comment: You can also define them in some other files and import them into `conftest.py`. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/peterhurford/09f7dcda0ab04b95c026c60fa49c2a68).